# Allow reorder of items in developer story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

When there are items that overlap on a developer story, I think it could be useful to give us the option to rearrange them as we want so that we can have our story make sense. Check out my story, while I was working at WiseClick, I got interested in communications... then, I wrote an article in my blog which led me to my next job.

The problem is that I can't show that right now, as I ended working at WiseClick on 5/14, my blogpost (dated 10/13) will always appear "earlier".

I'm guessing I'll just change the blog post date, to me the narrative is more important than when I wrote the article, but it would be nice to have it right ;)

[image: My Story]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Rearranging items in your story and emphasizing the ones you want are definitely something on our radar. Developers should be able to customize their story as they see fit.

Comment: Is there a timeframe for this functionality to be added in or is it down as 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @Stewartside We don't have a timeframe at the moment

Comment: @Stewartside 6-8 months (years?)

Comment: @Neal http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/280588 ;)

Comment: haha I know that one @Stewartside ;-P

Comment: Not weeks, not months, I guess it's years then?