# Developer Story: Timeline Sorting is Not Flexible

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

This has been somewhat addressed by [Timeline is hard to read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320183/timeline-is-hard-to-read), but I for one am fairly happy with the timeline, though good points are made in his argument.

My problem is with the sorting of the elements on the timeline, which seems to favor end dates over total length of time spent.

For example, if I spent 6 years at university, but got a job just 6 months before I graduated, it is listed as the job coming before university on the timeline. Some people might want this, since they are focussed on the graduation date, but others are more focussed on the learning journey, and see university as coming (mostly) before their job.

[image: Proof]

It'd be a nice touch to be able to:

**1) Manually sort the order of events**
(possibly only available if they overlap)

or

**2) Automatically sort based on the majority of which one came first**
(90% of my university came before my work)

Comment: We've received a lot of feedback on the sorting of the timeline events.  The team is currently looking at bugs, and urgent items that need fixing.  This is definitely up on the list to be addressed sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thanks - Sorry its already been addressed - I just noticed http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335766/allow-reorder-of-items-in-developer-story?rq=1